# My fish prompt gets messed up when I add more set_color

Tags: colors, prompt, fish

I've been trying to make a custom fish prompt, but there's one problem that I can't seem to figure out how to fix.

I got this to work, but it's not exactly what I want, as I want the `ash@cat-box` to be green
[image: working fish prompt]

Here's the one I tried to make it exactly what I wanted, but a lot of things get messed up in it and I don't understand why or how to fix it.
[image: not working fish prompt]

I would appreciate any help getting my prompt to work and explaining why it's doing what it does.

Comment: Add more information, e.g. what have you tried and how exactly did you try and the complete Fish configs.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is missing `%s` format specifiers in `printf`. `%s` tells printf to substitute an argument as a string. If you add more strings (in this case, the new calls to `set_color`) it will not know where to put them, so they just get added to the end.

A direct fix is to add more `%s` specifiers:

```bash
printf '%s%s@%s%s:%s%s%s$' (set_color green) $USER $hostname (set_color normal) \
                           (set_color blue) (prompt_pwd) (set_color normal)
```

however this is getting a little unwieldy; it might be more clear if these were broken up into separate commands:

```
function fish_prompt
    set_color green
    printf '%s@%s' $USER $hostname
    set_color normal
    printf ':'
    set_color blue
    printf '%s' (prompt_pwd)
    set_color normal
    printf '$ '
end
```